# Entity Framework .net 6.0 Sql Query Cant find

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I want to run the sp in the database. but sql query gives reference error. It doesn't suggest anything as a using instead.

code:

```
var allUsersAndCountry = context.Database.SqlQuery<ListTaskViewModel>("SP_GetAllUserForCountry @UserName, @CountryID", sqlparameters.ToArray());
```

error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error CS1061  'DatabaseFacade' does not contain a definition for
> 'SqlQuery' and no accessible extension method 'SqlQuery' accepting a
> first argument of type 'DatabaseFacade' could be found (are you
> missing a using directive or an assembly
> reference?)   DAL C:\Users\bfindik\Desktop\Gorev\Backend\DAL\Concrete\TaskRepository.cs   18  Active

Comment: `context.Database.FromSqlRaw<ListTaskViewModel>("EXEC SP_GetAllUserForCountry @UserName = {0}, @CountryID = {1}", sqlparameters.ToArray())` maybe?

Comment: @Charlieface Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1929 'DatabaseFacade' does not contain a definition for 'FromSqlRaw' and the best extension method overload 'RelationalQueryableExtensions.FromSqlRaw<ListTaskViewModel>(DbSet<ListTaskViewModel>, string, params object[])' requires a receiver of type 'DbSet<ListTaskViewModel>' DAL C:\Users\bfindik\Desktop\Gorev\Backend\DAL\Concrete\TaskRepository.cs 32 Active

Comment: `context.Database.ListTaskViewModel.FromSqlRaw("EXEC SP_GetAllUserForCountry @UserName = {0}, @CountryID = {1}", sqlparameters.ToArray())` maybe? Not sure what you have here. Are you using EF or EF Core, and which version?

Comment: This code, the ViewModel type and the path `DAL\Concrete\TaskRepository.cs` suggest there's a "bit" of confusion around ORMs, EF Core and application layers. EF is an ORM, not a data access library or driver, that's ADO.NET's job. EF works with *entities*, not presentation-level viewmodels. Those entities need to be configured, preferably as DbSet properties in the DbContext object.